# Ionic 3 path error while importing modules

Tags: ionic3

I’m gettind the error in the picture below while importing a module in app.module.ts

**Error:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBSf1.jpg

It seems to be a problem with the path reference, since I’m importing like

```
import { LoginPageModule } from '../pages/login/login.module';
```

It seems that I should put the full path, but when I try:

```
import { LoginPageModule } from 'src/app/pages/login/login.module';
```

I get an error saying “Path not found”, or the error in the picture returns

Since I’m a complete beginner, I don’t know what to do. Any help?

Comment: So when I do that, I shouldn't import the page in app.module.ts, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't import the "LoginPageModule" u can use the class name in quotes("LoginPage") directly where you want to be required.

**LoginPageModule.ts**

```
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './Login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
  ],
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

**LoginPage.ts**

```
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
rootPage:any = "LoginPage";
```

Comment: Should I import it at:

Comment: not required. we already declare and import  the page in LoginPageModule.ts file

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be using this setting all alog the project now!

Comment: It’s my pleasure